# Max In a C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find the 'biggest' element in a user made array ,by using the max function from the algorithm library/header.

I have done some research on the cplusplus reference site but there I only saw how to compare two elements using the max function. Instead I am trying to display the maximum number using a function 'max' ,without having to make a 'for' loop to find it.

For example:

Array: `array[]={0,1,2,3,5000,5,6,7,8,9}`
Highest value: `5000`

I have made this code but it gives me a bunch of errors, which can be the issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[11];
    int n = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       array[i] = i;
    }
    array[5] = 5000;
    max(array , array + n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::max_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array))`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: gcc didn't complain for `max((char*)array , array + n);`, but why?

Comment: @MikeCAT It gives you the larger of the two pointers (which will be `array+n`).

Comment: @MikeCAT max of 2 pointers? Seems reasonable that it would compile. Even legal and works as expected (returns the latter) since they are pointers into the same array.

Comment: +BoBTFish that gives me the adress of some element not the element itself

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc It gives you an iterator to that element (which in this case is a pointer, yes). You didn't really say how you want to use it. If you just want the value, you dereference the result.

Comment: Yes that's how it works.

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc Generally, "it gives me a bunch of errors" is not a good specification of problem. You should include the errors in your post instead. In this case, it's OK either way because it's such an easy question.

Comment: You have a bug, you are not initializing the last element in the array. Please see my answer.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you for this answer , but one more question , do I have to declare the 'iterator' header file ? --because you used the 'end' and the 'begin' functions.

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` come from the `<iterator>` header, yes. Although you can get away with using `array, array+n`, these functions are safer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`max_element` is the function you need. It returns an iterator to the max element in given range. You can use it like this:

```
cout << " max element is: " << *max_element(array , array + n) << endl;
```

Here you can find more information about this function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: Thank you for your quick response , but there is any way to find the maximum element in the array using only the 'max'  function ?

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc This is the version of the `max` function for ranges. It is exactly what you should use.

Comment: You can use only max function like this:
`int result = array[0];
 for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
  result = max(result, array[i]);
 }`
However I recommend using `max_element` as it is meant for solving your problem.

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc I don't understand the question. There is a `max` function that compares two numbers and returns the greater, and there is a `max_element` function that checks a range and returns a pointer to the largest element. Why do you want to use the version that only compares two elements without looping through the array, and what algorithm did you want to use then?

Comment: To make things more confusing, there's also a `max` overload that you can call like `std::max({a, b, c, d, e, f, g})`. That one is not as applicable to most situations, but can be handy when you need it.

Comment: It's worth adding that the initializer list version is available in C++11 and above.

Comment: The only caveat is that you have to use `n`, the option that uses `std::begin(array)` by @BoBTFish handles that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modification of your program that does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[11];
    int n = 11;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    array[5] = 5000;

    cout << *std::max_element(array, array + n) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you had a bug in your program, you did not initialize the last element in your array. This would cause your array to contain junk value in the last element. I've fixed that by increasing n to 11. Note that this is OK because the condition in the for loop is `i < n`, which means that i can be at most 10, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `std::array` by `#include<array>`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    array<int,10> arr;
    int n = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    arr[5] = 5000;
    
    cout<<"Max: "<< *max_element(arr.begin(),arr.end())<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

More info on [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)