# Max value of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How can I find max value of array using pointers? I must use cpp+header combo and [] is not allowed. Here is a part of the code.

main.cpp

```
const int NUMBERS = 30;

int main() {

int array[NUMBERS] = { 1, 3, 6, 9 };
sort(array, array + NUMBERS);

...

std::cout << max_v1(array, NUMBERS) << std::endl;
std::cout << max_v2(array, array + NUMBERS) << std::endl;
}
```

I got arrays.cpp and under it:

```
int max_v1(int *ptr, int size)
{
    //TODO
}

int max_v2(int *firstptr, int *lastptr)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Look at the ++ operator and the * operator for pointers

Comment: [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: Look up and study pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7719978/1896169

Comment: Can't use std::max_element. I must use what is given above.

Comment: There's a hint in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/10077

Comment: Other very related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34315002/1896169 https://stackoverflow.com/q/9653173/1896169

Comment: Thank you @FredLarson . That sucker is hard to Google.

Comment: What with all downvoting. @Justin I can't use [] that's the problem. I already googled for those topics. I wouldn't come here otherwise asking.

Comment: @4uvak91 What does "I can't use `[]`" mean? You cant write `firstptr[element]`?

Comment: @Justin: It appears the point of the assignment is to use pointer arithmetic instead of indexing.

Comment: Why do you need to **find** the largest element? You sorted the array. You already **know** where the largest element is.

Comment: @Justin Yes in arrays.cpp I can't use []-operator at all. I must use pointers. main.cpp is predefined.

Comment: @4uvak91 If you look at the question Fred Larson linked, the answers give you enough information to solve this

Comment: @4uvak91: "*Can't use `std::max_element`*" - then why are you allowed to use `std::sort()`? It doesn't make sense to use one part of the STL and not another.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yup the task explanation is very confusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little diagram to help you.

Array pointer to first element:

```
|1|3|6|9|
 ^
 ptr
```

Dereferencing to get value:

```
*ptr == 1
```

Array pointer + size (points past the last element):

```
|1|3|6|9|
         ^
         ptr + size
```

Array pointer to last element:

```
|1|3|6|9|
       ^
       ptr + size - 1
```

Dereferencing to get the value:

```
*(ptr + size - 1) == 9
```

Therefore the function 1 should look like this:

```
int max_v1(int *ptr, int size)
{
    return *(ptr + size - 1);
}
```

Would you be able to do the second function by yourself?

P.S. Make sure NUMBERS you pass as second argument is equal to the actual size of the array, or it won't work (for obvious reasons demonstrated above)

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the OP, but I believe by "max" he means the largest element in the array, not the item at the location of the largest index (but I could be wrong). Regardless though, I like your visualization of pointers with the array!

Comment: @scohe001: A sorted array has the largest element at the final position.

Comment: @scohe001 OP is using default `std::sort` to sort the array prior calling both functions, so it is safe to assume the array will be sorted and the last element will be greatest.

Comment: Yea I'm looking for largest element, but this helps a lot too. Very helpful.

Comment: Ahhh I completely missed that. Oops!

Comment: @KillzoneKid how can I iterate then if the array is not sorted?

Comment: Same way, the only difference sorting makes is that you do not need to check every element but go straight to the end. Otherwise you have to make a loop and check and compare each element of the array.